# Scope not doing what I expect with composite directives

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have set up a JS fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/gcCSG/) which shows a situation where a directive is composed from other directives. The scope object is not doing what I expect in this case.

The first control is composed in html, so there is a panel, inside that panel is a control, and inside the control is a button bound to "hi()" via ng-click. This scenario works fine since a transcluded scope is created.

In the second example the same visual effect is achieved but rather than specifying the panel explicity, it is declared in the controls template. The transcluded scopes go all weird here causing the ng-click not to fire.

I can get the event to fire by binding to '$parent.$parent.$parent.hi()'. I would expect the scope to perform the same way in both situations since (in my mind) it's effectively the same. Have I got it wrong?

Javascript:

```
angular
.module('demo', [])
.controller('MainController', function($scope) {
    $scope.hi = function() {
       alert('Button click was fired!');
    };
})
.directive('panel', function() {
    return {
        transclude: true,
        scope: {
            title: '@'
        },
        template: '<div class="panel"><h4>{{title}}</h4><div ng-transclude></div></div>'
    };
})
.directive('control', function() {
    return {
        transclude: true,
        scope: {
            label: '@'
        },
        template: '<div class="control"><h4>{{label}}</h4><div ng-transclude></div></div>'
    };
})
.directive('compositeControl', function() {
    return {
        transclude: true,
        scope: {
            label: '@'
        },
        template: '<div panel title="Panel with embedded control"><div class="control"><h4>{{label}}</h4><div ng-transclude></div></div></div>'
    };
});
```

Html:

```
<div ng-app="demo">

<div ng-controller="MainController">
    <h4>Button outside of transcluded scope</h4>
    <button ng-click="hi()">Button Outside</button>

    <h4>Working</h4>        
    <div panel title="Panel Title">
        <div control label="My Control Label">
            <button ng-click="hi()">Button Inside</button>
        </div>
    </div>        

    <h4>Broken</h4>        
    <div composite-control label="My Composite Control Label">
        <button ng-click="hi()">Button Inside</button>
    </div>      

    <h4>Working, but not really</h4>        
    <div composite-control label="My Composite Control Label">
        <button ng-click="$parent.$parent.$parent.hi()">Button Inside</button>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I think you're confused about transclusion... transclusion is for the HTML content of a directive, NOT for scopes.  By using the `{}` notation for your scopes, you're setting up isolate scopes that explicity DON'T inherit from parent.  See [the documentation on directives](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.$compile).  Sounds like you either want inheriting scopes, or you'll want to pass the function down to each new scope.

Comment: Thanks, will need to chew on this.